# Excel: IF statement with 3 possible outcomes (2 times text, 1 empty cell)

Tags: excel, if-statement

Situation:

Cell A1 is a number (age of a person)

Cell B1 generates one of 2 texts.

I can't get to the solution of this: If A1 is greater than 14 and less or equal to 17, it should give text A. If A1 is greater than 17, it should give text B. If A1 is empty, B1 should stay empty too.

Answer (score 1):

Nested IF

```
=IF(A1>17,"A",IF(A1>14,"B",""))
```

Comment: This is so short in comparison to what I found... I got a nested IF statement with and AND function in it to get the "number is between function". This is just the other way around and it works like a charm.

Thanks a bunch!